# create a directed graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

i want create a directed graph , i have three variables : String x,y,z
and the first vertex contain the 3 variables and the next contain the next 3 until the end of the loop

i have this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new StringReader(contentTextArea.getText()));

try {
  str =reader.readLine();

  while(str != null) {
    String splitted[] = str.split("\\|");
    String x = splitted[0].trim();
    String y = splitted[1].trim();
    String z = splitted[2].trim();
  }          
}
```

so this code give me each time 3 strings and i want for each time to create a vertex and an edge and this will create a graph at the end.
the code could be like this, but i don't know what to write inside 
`createVertex (String x,y,z)`,`addEdge ()` methods.

```
public class graph {  
  createVertex (String x,y,z);
  addEdge ();
}
```

Comment: you need an implementation  (a data structure etc) to hold the graph information. Depends on what operations you need for this graph, you should choose the right implementation (structure)

Comment: In addition to what Winfred said, I think you should reconsider the form of your input. You're creating "a vertex and an edge" every time? (1) What will you do when creating a graph that doesn't have the same number of vertices and of edges? (2) On the very first line, what two vertices is your edge going to join? -- Oh, and the signatures of your `createVertex` and `addEdge` don't make much sense to me. Three strings for `createVertex`? What are they for? No arguments to `addEdge`? What edge should it add, then?

Comment: I think the first thing we (and you) need to know is: What is this for? Why are you doing this? What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: You should also mention which library you use.

Comment: If you want to implement your own, you need to know what functions/operations you want to have for your graph:i.e. minimal distance, average bandwidth, checkforcyclic etc?.For example, http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/ is a graph library in Java ready to be be used.

Comment: What are you looking for? (1) code/algorithms implementing the directed graph (that is placement of vertexes, routing of edges, etc.), or (2) how to represent vertexes and edges as objects in java?

Comment: i have a file, and i want to create a graph contain the information of the file, so i want to put the information of each line in a vertex then add nn edge then create the next vertex from the next line until the end of the file

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question. Why do you have this file? Why do you want to create this graph? What are you going to do with it? What's the actual goal here?

Comment: because i want do graph matching after creating this graphs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a linestrip, i.e. each line represents a vertex and an edge is formed by two consecutive vertices you could create/use a `Vertex` class representing a vertex and an `Edge` class that has a reference to the 2 vertices that form its end points.

In your graph class you could then just have a list of vertices and a list of edges.
`createVertex()` could then just add a new vertex to the list whereas `addEdge()` would create an edge using the last two vertices on the list (if there are at least two!) and put the edge on the edge list.

If you later have edges that are formed by specific vertices (i.e. not the two last ones) you might use the index of each vertex in the list to reference them and define the edge via those indices (i.e. edge from vertex 0 to 5 could be defined as `0,5`).

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on how you are representing your graph. I would recommend using a third party library such as [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/) or [JGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org/). If you can't use a third party library (e.g. for homework or you just want to learn) then you need to define your own Graph class.

Two common representations are connectivity matrices and adjacency lists. Either representations could work for you.

Creating a new vertex is easy, just call addVertex on the JGraph graph. That will return a vertex object. You will need to provide it with two parameters, a name and a data object. For the name either use an incrementing id number or the original line string. You'll then need to create a data object out of the three strings, providing a custom data object makes the most sense to me.

I would keep track of the last node inserted (starts null) and then create edges between vertices whenever the previous i s not null. Making sure to update the previous vertex every iteration.

Comment: addEdge is between two consecutive vertices